# Where is mapping of __default__ user to unconfined_u defined in SELinux policy?

Tags: linux, security, selinux

`semanage login -l` shows following mappings

```
~]# semanage login -l

Login Name                SELinux User              MLS/MCS Range

__default__               unconfined_u              s0-s0:c0.c1023
root                      unconfined_u              s0-s0:c0.c1023
system_u                  system_u                  s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

So, these are the default mappings. I want to learn where the mapping of `__default__` to `unconfined_u` is defined. I want to update this mapping **in** the policy itself. I know this mapping can be changed later on using `semanage login` command, but I want to change it in the policy itself. Thank you.

Comment: Download the source, then?